# How does the database decide which Index to use

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, performance, sql-server-2005, query-performance

### DDL

```
create table t
(
    id int,
    id1 int
)

create index Example_Index
  On t(id,id1)

create index Example1_Index
  On t(id1,id)
```

---

### DML

```
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 100)
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 101)
insert into t(id, id1)values(2, 103)
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 104)
insert into t(id, id1)values(3, 105)
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 106)
insert into t(id, id1)values(2, 107)
insert into t(id, id1)values(3, 108)
```

---

**Sql Query** - `select * from t Where id = 107`  -- uses `Example_Index`

**Sql Query** - `select * from t Where id1 = 107` -- uses `Example1_Index`

**Sql Query** - `select * from t`                 -- uses `Example1_Index`

**Confusion** - How does the system decides to use `Example1_Index`

Below are the details...

[image]

Comment: SQL Server determines the index to use largely from statistics, and you do not have enough data in these tables for it to matter.  SQL Server knows this ...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The index created latest is used or index with higher index id is being used.This is shown in below query but this is just the observation based on below query and might not be consistent behaviour as i couldnt find any documentaion from MS related to this.
Run below query and then run the same by swapping the two index creation statements.

But as long as optimizer picks the best index it shouldnt bother you.In this case both indexes are same.

```
drop table t
go
create table t 
( 
    id int, 
    id1 int 
) 


create index Example_Index 
  On t(id,id1) 

 create index Example1_Index 
  On t(id1,id) 
 go
 insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 100) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 101) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(2, 103) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 104) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(3, 105) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(1, 106) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(2, 107) 
insert into t(id, id1)values(3, 108) 
go
select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(9,object_id('t'),null,null,'DETAILED')
go
dbcc freeproccache
go
select * from t Where id = 107 -- uses Example_Index

select * from t Where id1 = 107 -- uses Example1_Index

select * from t -- uses Example1_Index
go
dbcc freeproccache
go
select * from t Where id = 107 -- uses Example_Index

select * from t -- uses still Example1_Index even though that index is not used at all.However, this index id is 3 higher than example_index.
go
--now try the same thing but change the order of the index and you will see example_index is used.
```

Comment: You might observe that behavior immediately, but what about over time? I'd be very careful about making your observation sound factual or guaranteed.

Comment: I am not saying that this is consistent behaviour because i have tried just one or two scenarios.Also, I do not know someone in Microsof to confirm this behaviour.Also till now I have not seen any documentation,there might exists but i havent see it yet.I have mentioned in the end that as long as the optimizer is picking correct index we should not bother how it selects between two indexes which are same as is in this case.

Comment: Your first sentence sounds like you are stating a fact, when in truth that isn't a fact at all, unless you have some reference you can point to. Please don't state singular observations as facts; these lead to incorrect assumptions and myths.

Comment: Changed the sentense.Hoepfully, it doesnt sound fact now.

Comment: Need some time to look into it i will revert very soon

Answer (score 11):

First two queries are self-explanatory - they're performing a seek on the leading column in the chosen index.

Third one is a coin-flip since, without a clustered index, both indexes have the same cost.

You *might* observe that the most recently-used index (from query 2) will be used for query 3 - but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Does that mean - in case of 3rd query execution `Example1_Index` execution is just a random case and it can be `Example_Index` also ?

Comment: It could be, yes. This is all cost-based and those two indexes have the same cost if you're using `SELECT *` and there is no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why does SQL Server use *any* index in the 3rd case?

Comment: @pst it doesn't necessarily have to. Since there is no clustered index on the table, and the index contains all of the columns in the table, it is likely also a coin-flip with a table scan. But I'd bet there's something in the optimizer code that leans toward an index.

Comment: @RGI you added a screen shot of the index scan we already knew was happening. What does that change about your question, the answer, or these comments?

Comment: @Aaron - as pst told **Why does SQL Server use any index in the 3rd case?**....

Comment: @RGI did you read my reply to his comment? It starts with `@pst`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no certainty that which index executes.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more...? Thanks for the reply....

Comment: consider a query. select * from tablename where 1=1 or 2=2 or 3=3. Do you think 2=2 or 3=3 will ever execute as in an OR statement, logically if first statement is true, it shouldn't execute the remaining statement. But sql server makes a random execution plan sometimes, according to the time taken.  Similarly in your case, one can never be sure that which index would be executed/.

Comment: Did you check my first two queries? I understand that these two uses the mentioned indexes in my query. Can you confirm my understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

Index creation is the crucial thing in DB. In large database it shows a major role during the search of particular record set.

> So first of all when you search the record so on the basis of search
>   criteria the DB engine try to search the record through index. If it
>   find the right index the query is said to be optimized and if it
>   doesn't then engine mark the this index as a missing index and finally
>   provide the result set very slow.

For finding the missing index you can run :

**Select * from dm_db_missing_index_details**

Here you will get equality_Columns, Non_equalityColumns, and included columns.
so on the basis of these details you can prepare the right index for your search criteria.

For Ex:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyIndex ON
dbo.Mytable(ListOfEqualityColumns_separatedByCommas,ListOf_NONE_qualityColumns_separatedByCommas)
INCLUDE (ListOf_Included_Columns_separatedByCommas); 
GO
```