# What does MySQL actually use to decide which index should be used?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, execution-plan, mysql-5.7

I know there is already similar question here like [How does the database decide which Index to use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21183/how-does-the-database-decide-which-index-to-use). But it seems that those answers are not cool and useless.

In my development and use of MySQL, I found there are multiple factors that affect how MySQL decides which index should be used to execute the SQL statements. Those factors include but are not limited to:

1. The estimated scan count of rows for certain index.
2. The `order by` condition and whether certain index would cause `filesort`.
3. The presence of `limit 0,N` condition and even the value of N would impact the result.

Any response from people who have read the source code or have developed MySQL source codes will be highly appreciated! :)

If you know someone who maybe knows the answers, please share this page with them.

Answer (score 1):

- What is in the `WHERE` clause.
- An estimation of how many rows will be fetched -- to decide whether to use an index, or simply scan the table.
- Size of two tables in a `JOIN` -- if there is no other good way to decidw which table to start with.
- The value of N in a `LIMIT` rarely matters.
- Whether the columns's datatypes match -- mismatch of `COLLATION` may inhibit use of an index.
- Not used: whether the needed blocks is already cached in RAM.
- Not used: Spinning disk vs SSD.  (There is a tunable in 8.0 to help.)
- In certain situations, an index is dynamically created for a subquery.
- Size of the index.
- "Cost" of the various options.
- `ORDER BY` is used only if the entire `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` are handled first.  Or the Optimizer may skip the `WHERE` and only use an index for the `ORDER BY`, thereby avoiding 'filesort'.
- `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, of not compatible enough may lead to two filesorts.

See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for some extra clues.  See also the "Optimizer trace".

[*My cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) approaches your question in a different way...  "Given this `SELECT`, what is the best `INDEX` for it?"